# Put CSV Data Using jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to update a spreadsheet on a website with a jQuery ajax call through an api.  The rest API that I'm using requires that I use a [PUT request with csv data](https://www.socialtext.net/st-rest-docs/%2Fdata%2Fworkspaces%2F%3Aws%2Fsheets%2F%3Asheetname).  When I execute the below script, I get a 204 content created, but when I visit the page, my content isn't added.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/data/workspaces/yada/sheets/yada',
    type:'PUT',
    data:'a,b,c;d,e,f'
})
```

How do I properly include my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the contentType:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/data/workspaces/yada/sheets/yada',
    contentType: "text/csv",
    type:'PUT',
    data:'a,b,c;d,e,f'
})
```

Comment: haha, thanks, I thought I had tried that earlier but I guess not.  Thank you.